# what is __imp__malloc in a mingw-32 linked program?

Tags: mingw, nm

In am attempt to figure out if `malloc()` in my cross-compiled mingw32 program is threadsafe or not, I ran `nm` on the binary. The results:

```
$ i386-mingw32-nm myfile.exe  | grep malloc
00ab04fc I __imp__malloc
005b8e70 T _malloc
$
```

For comparison, here is a search for `GetLastError`, which is used but not defined in my program:

```
$ i386-mingw32-nm myfile.exe  | grep GetLastError
005b9034 T _GetLastError@0
00ab0370 I __imp__GetLastError@0
$
```

And here is a search for something I know is in my program:

```
$ i386-mingw32-nm myfile.exe  | grep ends_with
0040a98d T _ends_with
$
```

I *think* that this means that `malloc()` in my C library is provided as a cover to a system `malloc()`, as is `GetLastError()`, but that `ends_with()` doesn't appear in the system. But I'd like a second opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mingw does not use its own `malloc`, it links the Windows `malloc`. So yes, it is threadsafe, because Windows is.